# How to increase the show time of toastNotification in uwp?

Tags: c#, xml, notifications, windows-store-apps, uwp

I am creating application using **scheduled Toast Notification**. I want to increase the show time of the Notification. How can i set the time for display the notification. Is there any other option for this?

Comment: If you are using phone to look something, toast Notification appear suddenly, and then it disappear fast. you want to increase the show time of  toast notification, am I right?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/02/adaptive-and-interactive-toast-notifications-for-windows-10/) you can use the `duration` property of your Toast Notification XML to display it either for a `short` (7s) or `long` (25s) time:

```
<toast duration="long">
    <visual ... />
</toast>
```

> This attribute was introduced back in Windows 8 time-frame for specifying how long the toast notification stays on the screen – setting the value to “short” will make the notification display for  ~7 seconds and setting it to “long” will make the notification display for ~25 seconds.
>
> In Windows 10, developers have the following options to keep the notification on screen for longer than standard length (~7 seconds):
>
> - Specifying scenario attribute (see description below) to “alarm” or “reminder” to persist the notification on screen until the user dismisses it.
> - Specify duration attribute to “long” while making sure the scenario attribute is specified to “default” or unspecified. This will result in the legacy behavior of notification showing on screen for ~25 seconds.
>
>   We do not recommend using this property unless you have a good reason to keep the notification up for ~25 seconds on screen. This attribute exists mainly for appCompat reason.

Further you can create a `reminder` notification to keep it visible until the user interacts with:

```
<toast scenario="reminder">
    <visual ... />
</toast>
```

Note as stated in the documentation:

> Do not use this just for keeping your notification persistent on screen.