# windows.ui.notifications API → decrease the time the notification appears on the screen to less than 7 seconds

Tags: python, windows, notifications, toast

With this code I can generate my toast notification:

```
from winsdk.windows.ui.notifications import ToastNotificationManager, ToastNotification, ToastTemplateType
import datetime

def toast_notification(AppID, title, text):
    XML = ToastNotificationManager.get_template_content(ToastTemplateType.TOAST_TEXT02)
    t = XML.get_elements_by_tag_name("text")
    t[0].append_child(XML.create_text_node(title))
    t[1].append_child(XML.create_text_node(text))
    notifier = ToastNotificationManager.create_toast_notifier(AppID)
    toaster = ToastNotification(XML)
    toaster.expiration_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
    notifier.show(toaster)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    toast_notification('Visual Studio Code','title', 'text')
```

But the notification keeps for 7 seconds appearing on the screen instead of just 1 second.

**Update question:**

[aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8601760/aaron) brought us some important information:

`expiration_time` is the time the notification is archived in the *Action Center*, so with it I would never be able to reduce the time the notification stays on the screen.

Comment: https://github.com/pywinrt/python-winsdk/issues/14

Comment: Hi @aaron (I created this issue), the module has been updated, it no longer delivers the error because it accepts ```datetime```, but the toast notification continues in screen for 7 seconds instead of just 1 second as it should be.

Comment: `expiration_time` determines whether it should be shown at a certain time, not how long it is shown for. Try `duration` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40798377/how-to-increase-the-show-time-of-toastnotification-in-uwp) or `scenario` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52424759/change-the-duration-of-an-windows-toast-c-sharp) on the toast content (XML).

Comment: Really @aaron now I understand, ```expiration_time``` is the time it stays in the action center, not appearing on the screen. In the indicated options, there is only way to increase the time, but decreasing the time of 7 seconds on the screen does not seem to be possible (in this option using ```windows.ui.notifications```).

Comment: And @aaron there are some modules for Python that you can put any amount, but there is a problem, if two codes send notifications at the same time, it breaks because of something called ```Shell_NotifyIconW``` failed, it doesn't generate a notification queue equal to the ```windows.ui.notifications```.